# Regex for VBA Excel macro for new folder chars

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function which is Boolean, and returns whether is the cell OK for creating a New Folder based on its value or its not (if it posses following chars:<,>,|,\,*,?)

But from some weird reason, it returns always false, either is a cell OK or not.
So, I have a sub which creates a loop for all rows and creates some .txt files and puts it in auto-generated folders.

Here is my code:

```
Sub CreateTxtSrb()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iFile As Integer
Dim sPath As String
Dim sFile As String
Dim iEnd As Range
'iEnd = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For iRow = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    iFile = FreeFile
With Rows(iRow)
    If IsValidFolderName(.Range("B2").Value) = False Or IsValidFolderName(.Range("D2").Value) = False Or IsValidFolderName(.Range("F2").Value) = False Then
        MsgBox ("Check columns B,D or F, it cannot contains chars: <,>,?,|,\,/,*,. or a space at the end")
        Exit Sub
    Else
    strShort = IIf(InStr(.Range("E2").Value, vbCrLf), Left(.Range("E2").Value, InStr(.Range("E2").Value, vbCrLf) - 2), .Range("E2").Value)
        sPath = "E:\" & .Range("B2").Value & "\"
        If Len(Dir(sPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir sPath
        sFile = .Range("D2").Value & ".txt"
        Open sPath & sFile For Output As #iFile
        Print #iFile, .Range("E2").Value
        Close #iFile
    End If
End With
Next iRow
End Sub

Function IsValidFolderName(ByVal sFolderName As String) As Boolean
'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-   us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#file_and_directory_names
'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms974570.aspx
 On Error GoTo Error_Handler
 Dim oRegEx          As Object

'Check to see if any illegal characters have been used
Set oRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
oRegEx.Pattern = "[&lt;&gt;:""/\\\|\?\*]"
IsValidFolderName = Not oRegEx.test(sFolderName)
'Ensure the folder name does end with a . or a blank space
If Right(sFolderName, 1) = "." Then IsValidFolderName = False
If Right(sFolderName, 1) = " " Then IsValidFolderName = False

Error_Handler_Exit:
On Error Resume Next
Set oRegEx = Nothing
Exit Function

Error_Handler:
MsgBox ("test")
'    MsgBox "The following error has occurred" &amp; vbCrLf &amp; vbCrLf &amp; _
'           "Error Number: " &amp; Err.Number &amp; vbCrLf &amp; vbCrLf &amp; _
'           "Error Source: IsInvalidFolderName" &amp; vbCrLf &amp; _
'           "Error Description: " &amp; Err.Description, _
'           vbCritical, "An Error has Occurred!"
Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Function
```

How can I make it return true if need be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the external reference you can simply:

```
hasInvalidChars = sFolderName like "*[<>|\/:*?""]*"
```

I added `"` and `:` which are also illegal.

(In your example you have HTML entities (E.g. `&lt;`) - these have no meaning in your RegEx string and are interpreted as 4 characters in the class)

Comment: Thanks Alex, your solution is more elegant. I didn't realize a method "like". Everyday something new. :)

Answer (score 1):

That's a mess. Use a separate function

```
Public Function IsInvalid(ByVal name As String) As Boolean
    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = VBA.CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regex.Pattern = "[\\/:\*\?""<>\|]" 'the disallowed characters
    IsInvalid = (regex.Execute(name).Count > 0)
End Function
```

instead, and call it when appropriate.